# C# SOAP Using Vertex Tax Collection Service How to display response of EffectiveRate

Tags: c#, soap, console-application

Using C# in a console app I need to collective the response for EffectiveRate from the SOAP response for Vertex WS60Client.  It returns it within an array and I just can't seem to set it to a variable.

```
    VertexEnvelope ve = new VertexEnvelope();

    calculateTaxResponse cTR = new calculateTaxResponse(ve);


decimal[] strTAX_RATE = new decimal[1];
                        strTAX_RATE[0] = ((TaxCodeCollector.CalculateTaxService.TaxesType)ve.Item).EffectiveRate;
```

Which just doesn't work

Comment: What's the error message? Is `EffectiveRate` of type `decimal`?

Comment: Unrelated note about the [tag:visual-studio]. If you read the description, it says *DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*, so it should not be used in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking, I did figure it out...

```
decimal strTAX_RATE = 0;
strTAX_RATE = ((TaxCodeCollector.CalculateTaxService.InvoiceResponseType)ve.Item).LineItem[0].Taxes[0].EffectiveRate;
```

I was taking the output from the wrong place when looking at the response set.